# My answer got deleted without a trace?

Tags: support, comments, moderation, comment-flags

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296787/how-do-i-add-to-the-assembly-gettypes-array-of-an-assembly?noredirect=1#comment41262779_26296787

I found my own answer and I was very happy about it. I'm very sure I posted it. Maybe I deleted it myself because I got downvoted but I would still like to know who or why it got deleted. I remember clearly writing "HOLY SHIT[...]" in some variation because I got it working.

Comment: There are no deleted answers on that question. I see a deleted **comment**. Perhaps that should have been an answer (minus the expletives)?

Comment: You never posted any... unless it got wiped by a data relocation mishap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had a comment deleted not an answer.  Comments are ephemeral and can be deleted by moderators or by other users if they are flagged.

Your comment was unilaterally deleted by another user because it contained a word that is blacklisted (aka "shit").  A user flagged it as not constructive and since it contained that word, it was removed.

Minus the blacklisted stuff, the comment was:

> Oh my god that is awesome. I wish there was better support for .netmodules in Visual Studio though, I have to use cmd line stuff and copy them around. But wow, that is really really cool. Yeah in fact, I only tried to create a .netmodule with a single c# file, I guess it will be a pain in the ass to construct the necessary cmdline for my huge project with lots of assembly references... damn hm, maybe I can do an addon to the msbuild pipeline to make this work with VS –  Blub Oct 10 at 10:57

Comment: Can I somehow get it back?

Comment: @Blub I can't undelete the comment, but I've included it in my answer without the blacklisted stuff.  Feel free to post a new version.